# Rails skip all before filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

can anyone tell me how to skip all before filters in rails 3.

In rails 2.x we could do

```
skip_filter filter_chain
```

however filter_chain is no longer supported in rails 3.

Thanks

Answer (score 18):

Try this

```
skip_filter *_process_action_callbacks.map(&:filter)
```

Method `_process_action_callbacks` should return [CallbackChain](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb#L326) instance, which is an array of [Callback](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb#L84)s
And since Callback#filter gets the name of the callback, this works:

```
before_filter :setup
_process_action_callbacks.map(&:filter) #=> [:setup]
```

Comment: Need to splat the argument for this to work: `skip_filter(*_process_action_callbacks.map(&:filter))

Answer (score 10):

Need to skip *all* filters is likely caused by inheriting from a custom ApplicationController.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # defines multiple `before_filter`s common to most controllers

class SomeController < ApplicationController
  # this controller may be fine with inheriting all filters

class AnotherController < ApplicationController
  # but this one not!
```

In my example scenario, instead of removing the `before_filter`s from `AnotherController`, just let it inherit from `ActionController::Base`.

Answer (score 4):

Haven't tried it, but this might work:

```
[:before, :after, :around].each {|type| reset_callbacks(type)}
```

Comment: `reset_callbacks` will delete the callback completely for the whole controller and won't allow `:except` or `:only` keywords. If this is acceptable, it is better and more forward compatible than my code.

Answer (score 4):

For Rails 5, I've used

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController    

  skip_before_action *_process_action_callbacks.map{|callback| callback.filter if callback.kind == :before}.compact
```

You must check the callback.kind, otherwise _process_action_callbacks will return all callbacks, including `after` and `around`, which will raise an exception with `skip_before_action` method.

The `.compact` at the end removes `nils` from the resulting array.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to specify :only or :except to skip_filter, use the following :

```
skip_filter(:only => [:method1, :method2], *_process_action_callbacks.map(&:filter))
```

Xavier Shay put me on the right direction, but then I struggled a bit to figure out I had to put :only before the list of filters to skip!

Edit : the solution above is for RUby 1.8.7. For Ruby 1.9 you'd do :

```
skip_filter(*_process_action_callbacks.map(&:filter), :only => [:method1, :method2])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly hacking deep inside Rails belly and you would be better off specifying the callbacks by hand, but the following line will do the job:

```
eval %[skip_filter #{_process_action_callbacks.select { |c|
    [:before, :after, :around].include? c.kind }.collect{|c|
      c.filter.inspect}.join(", ")
    }]
```

You can also add `:only => :index` etc modifications to the eval just before the ending `]` to further modify the call if needed.

Answer (score -4):

```
 skip_before_filters
```

http://ap.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html#M000132

Comment: There's no such method!

Comment: @vemv http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods/skip_before_filter

Comment: That skips a single filter, right? Its name is in singular, unlike the method name specified in your answer.